# Vector indexing for short

Tags: c++, stl, vector

Suppose I have a vector

`std::vector<a> A;`

I can get access to its member-functions through the `.` operator and I can index it with the `[]` operator. If I have a pointer to a vector, e.g.

`std::vector<a> *A;`

I can get to its members using the short `->` operator, but indexing is very inconvenient, i.e. `(*A)[i]`. How can it be written more neatly? **Note:** I am not satisfied with `A->at()`, because it does boundary check, which are slow, and for me speed is important.

Comment: "indexing is very inconvenient", really? Three extra characters to type? It's not even particularly nasty to read.

Comment: Yes, really. I am writing programs for scientific computing and a structure like pointer to a vector of pointers to vectors. In that case it looks like this (*(*A)[i])[j] and you have to type it all the function long...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Bind it to a reference is the easiest way if `(*A)[i]` is a problem:

```
std::vector<a>& ref = *A;
ref[i] = 0; //use reference
```

Normally I'd prefer passing vectors by reference instead of pointer anyway unless you really want to allow `NULL` values too.